# Почему ребёнок ошибся?

Tags: орфография

Несколько дней назад С. написал следующий заголовок к выполненным им математическим упражнениям: "СКАЛЬАРНОЕПРОИ...ВЕДЕНИЕ ВИКТАРОВ", где вместо трёх точек стоял символ, совпадающий с зеркальным отражением буквы "З".

Какие ошибки и почему ребёнок шести лет допустил в выражении "скалярное произведение векторов"?

Answer (score 4):

Не думаю, что здесь кроется что-то удивительное. Все эти ошибки часто встречаются у детей. Меня больше удивляет то, что в шесть лет он уже пишет о векторах.

Во первых, пропуск пробела. Часто дети задумываются и забывают про них. Если ребёнок сосредоточен на буквах, то такие мелочи как пробел могут ускользнуть из внимания, поскольку ещё не вошли в привычку. Потом, некоторые долго не могут понять зачем вообще нужны пробелы, если мы произносим слова слитно.

Следующее, написание греческого эпселона вместо русской З. Тоже не редкая ошибка. Я сама долго не могла разобраться с ней когда училась писать. Здесь могут учавствовать несколько факторов. Возможно, потому что многие несимметричные буквы русского алфавита "раскрываются" направо: Б, В, Е, К, Р, С... Почти все кроме Э, Я, и З следуют этой закономерности. Возможна и путаница с цифрой 3. Если цифра пишется "налево", значит буква должна отличатся и писаться "направо". Или может быть эта буква ещё не "уселась" у ребёнка в уме, надо просто ещё немного времени и тренеровки чтобы её укрепить.

Написание ЬА вместо Я. Ребёнок слышит звук А, но чувствует мягкую Л, а связи с буквой Я ещё нету. Ещё не понятно, что Я, Ё, Ю, И, Е "содержат" в себе мягкий знак.

И и А в слове ВЕКТОРОВ. Ребёнок неправильно склоняет слово ВЕКТОР: вместо вЕкторов получается векторОв. Две первые гласные не ударные, а ребёнок не проверяет.

Вот и получается, что все ошибки связаны с психикой не меньше чем со знанием языка, и все они - дело привычки. Нужно увидеть слово несколько раз в правильном написание и повторить самому, тогда со временем оно уляжется.

Comment: Большое спасибо.